# How will I change scale of the parent GameObject without affecting the Child GameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity I am trying to make the character crouch by scaling it's localScale.y and CapsuleCollider.height variables. But, if I change the localScale on the y axis of the parent GameObject which is the player, it's gun also gets scaled and it looks like it has been squished.

How will I change the localScale.y variable of the parent GameObject without affecting it's Cild GameObject?

Comment: That defeats the purpose of the hierarchy. Make a new GameObject that contains only the objects you want to scale, and scale *that*.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options here, first you can separate the hierarchy as mentioned by 3Dave to immediately resolve this.

Second you can use the Unity animator to create an animation that scales the object and adjust the scale of the child to counteract the parent scale.

Third (really not recommended) to create a complicated calculation to sort of inverse the scale of the parent i.e. if parent scale is 0.9, 0.9, 0.9 set the child to 1.1, 1.1, 1.1 and etc ( Not even sure this would work ).

There might be something else you can do, but these are the 3 solutions that immediately pop up in my head.

Comment: Isn't second and third actually the same thing? ;) Except that with the animation you calculate the scale fixed to your keyframes while in the third you let the code do it on runtime

Comment: Yes pretty much, though animation is almost automated while coding it yourself is a bit more complicated